# php print array values as song title

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = new array('mike will made-it', 'miley cyrus', 'wiz khalifa', 'juicy j');
```

- If there is one element: **mike will made-it**
- If two **mike will made-it ft. miley cyrus**
- If more than two **mike will made-it ft. miley cyrus, wiz khalifa and
  juicy j**

Here is what I have done so far but I think It is a simple and faster way to do this.

```
public function get_artist() {
            $artists = 'Mike WiLL Made-It,Miley Cyrus,Wiz Khalifa, Juicy J';

            $artist_array = explode(',', $artists);

            if(sizeof($artist_array) == 1)
                return $artist_array[0];
            else if(sizeof($artist_array) == 2) {
                return $artist_array[0] . ' ft. ' . $artist_array[1];
            } else if(sizeof($artist_array) > 2) {
                //echo sizeof($artist_array);
                $ar = '';
                foreach($artist_array as $k=>$v) {
                        if($k == 0)
                            $v .= ' ft. ';
                        else if($k > 0 && ($k < (sizeof($artist_array) - 2)))
                             $v .= ', ';
                        else if($k == (sizeof($artist_array) - 1))
                            $v = ' and ' . $v;

                            $ar .= $v;
                }
                return $ar;
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = '';
$index  = 0;
$count  = count($artists);

foreach ($artists as $artist) {
    if ($count >= 2) {
        if ($index === 1) {
            $separator = ' ft. ';
        } elseif ($index === $count - 1) {
            $separator = ' and ';
        } else {
            $separator = ', ';
        }

        $result .= $separator;
        $index++;
    }

    $result .= $artist;
}

return $result;
```

Comment: It works but I need to show `and` before the last artist if there are  3 or more artists like this `mike will made-it ft. miley cyrus, wiz khalifa and juicy j` @Robo

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix it anyway for the `and` part. See my answer.

Comment: Why use foreach when you have a variable $index here? Then you're better and "more efficient" with a for :)

Comment: Because this is totally neglectable overhead and foreach is way more elegant. Your multiple calls of `sizeof` are something to be worried about. Plus, `count` function is preferable over `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = '';

foreach ($artists as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k == 1) {
        $result .= ' ft. ';
    } else if ($k > 1) {
         if ($k <= sizeof($artists) - 2) {
            $result .= ', ';
        } else if ($k == sizeof($artists) - 1) {
            $result .= ' and ';
        }
    }

    $result .= $v;
}

return $result;
```